# Network configuration of a virtual cluster with nested virtualization

Tags: networking, virtualbox, routing, qemu, cluster

I am trying to configure a virtual cluster with VirtualBox instances, which in turn, run another virtual machine (this one created with QEMU).

The following figure depicts the current set up where my local network is 192.168.3.0/24 and my computer running VirtualBox is 192.168.3.30:

[image]

In VirtualBox I've launched 2 hosts with their own intranet configured in VirtualBox with a dedicated NIC attached to the NAT Network 192.168.1.0/24.

Although all the nodes are in the same network 192.168.1.0/24 the nested guests (Vec) cannot communicate with remote hosts or vecs (red-crossed lines), but host-host and host-vec within the same host are able to communicate.

How should I configure the cluster to communicate them all?

**/etc/hosts**

```
192.168.1.1   host1
192.168.1.101    vec1
192.168.1.2  host2
192.168.1.102    vec2
192.168.1.3   host3
192.168.1.103    vec3
```

**host1$ ifconfig**

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe3e:1348  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:3e:13:48  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 58  bytes 4608 (4.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 156  bytes 10438 (10.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.3.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.3.255
        inet6 fe80::e22:2cf6:8579:39a3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:fa:c6:ca  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1169  bytes 94446 (92.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1778  bytes 207624 (202.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe3e:1348  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:3e:13:48  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11  bytes 632 (632.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 29  bytes 1990 (1.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 155  bytes 13078 (12.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 155  bytes 13078 (12.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::f81f:daff:fe5c:f05a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:1f:da:5c:f0:5a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2  bytes 144 (144.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**host1$ route**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         host1           0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 enp0s8
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.3.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 enp0s8
```

**vec1$ ifconfig**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::99a6:f5d6:71e4:a028  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fec0::678f:ac2f:8ada:2d1b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x40<site>
        ether 52:54:00:12:34:56  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 65  bytes 9318 (9.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 109  bytes 12408 (12.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::3aca:9bbc:c0c2:b316  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:12:34:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 177  bytes 17301 (16.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 99  bytes 13429 (13.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 56  bytes 4308 (4.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 56  bytes 4308 (4.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**vec1$ route**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
default         host1           0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```

**host2$ ifconfig**

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee0:d7cc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:e0:d7:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1911  bytes 145413 (142.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1909  bytes 284175 (277.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee0:d7cc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:e0:d7:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1646  bytes 105269 (102.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1722  bytes 265083 (258.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 76  bytes 5018 (4.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 76  bytes 5018 (4.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::f81f:daff:fe5c:f05a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:1f:da:5c:f0:5a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 75  bytes 8965 (8.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 105  bytes 12449 (12.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**host2$ route**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         host1           0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**vec2$ ifconfig**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.2.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.2.255
        inet6 fe80::99a6:f5d6:71e4:a028  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fec0::678f:ac2f:8ada:2d1b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x40<site>
        ether 52:54:00:12:34:56  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 16  bytes 1888 (1.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 64  bytes 8654 (8.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.102  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::4e5e:dfc8:2e9f:6072  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 52:54:00:12:34:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 154  bytes 16347 (15.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 131  bytes 15713 (15.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 76  bytes 7162 (6.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 76  bytes 7162 (6.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**vec2$ route**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
default         host1           0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eth1
```

Comment: A hint,...255.255.255.0 subnet with 2 ip ranges, and no gateways? You should be setting your "lan" according to your router settings, where your dhcp is, or expand your subnet and replace 255.255.255.0 with 255.255.0.0 on all devices(router included).

Comment: @Danijel I just need to connect host1, host2, vec1, and vec2 among them in 192.168.1.0/24. There is no need for them to go to 192.168.3.0/24 (just host1, and it is already configured).

Comment: Ahhh,oversight..Thinking from hyper-v perspective, shouldn't your vecs have same eth0 ip range then? are eth0 and eth1 teamed or, where is their virtual-switch on host? You connect client and hosts with virtualbox virtual-switch i assume(i didtn work with QEMU at all), do you have the same on hosts for vecs? did you try to "pass-tru" vec connection on host network, to see if vecs can communicate at all?

Comment: @Danijel what I tried was to connect vecs to hosts in the same network (192.168.1.0). Hosts are connected to virtualbox via a bridge. I do not know how to "pass-tru" vec's connection. Thanks

Comment: *Bridge vac eth to host eth